# Custom installer to install a PHP web site?

Tags: php, windows, web, installation

Just a quick one about installing a PHP website, are there any tools out there that would allow me to create an install package to fully install this website on a Windows platform? If possible maybe even take details like company name and database connections which then maybe updates the necessary PHP files?

If the later cannot be done its fine, but a free tool for installation would be great!

Thank you!

Ash.

Comment: Install wampserver and create a shortcut on your desktop to you index page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with a tool like [innosetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).
It let you build setup , in which you can put what ever you want (webpage , other setup ...).

If you want to do something a little bit advanced (installing apache , configuring file ...) you will need to do some code (delphi) , but the documentation is pretty clear about all the possibility.

Don't be fooled by the simplicity of the tool , it's very powerfull. For example you can check if a specific service is running to lauch (or not) a specific part of your setup. (if httpd is running just copy the webpage a skip the apache installation for example).

Answer (score 1):

You can combine innosetup with [server2go](http://www.server2go-web.de/download/download.html)
Download the package you want as a .ZIP file, extract it, put your website in "htdocs" folder and then create an installer with innosetup.

Edit: You can edit pms_config.ini too with your needs.